# new string(byte[]) too slow in multithreaded applications

Tags: java, string, multithreading

I noticed that when I call `new String(byte[])` from a single thread, it's pretty fast. But when I call it from several different threads it becomes painfully slow.

For example I have a parser that makes calls to `new String(bytes)`. If I called the parser 50 times sequentially each parse takes about 100ms, but if I make 50 threads and call the parse, each parse takes between 12000ms to 21000ms! (it becomes slower in the later threads). It seems as if the String(bytes) construction is defined to be synchronized.

The profiler tracked the bottleneck to `new String(bytes)` and indeed when I changed it to `new String("Hello")` the parser became as fast in multi-thread as it was in single thread.

Does anyone know why this is the case? And what's the workaround?

**Update:**
My verification test was wrong because apparently Java compiler has some internal optimizations that shares String objects instead of creating new ones when I call new `String("Hello")`. So that's why it was faster when I made that change. I will rewrite my test code and will update this question.

**Answer:**
Both @nafas and @peter answers below are correct. The String itself was not slow, but the profiler mistakenly identified them as the bottleneck. The real culprits were:

1. Having more threads than available cores.
2. Garbage collector pausing the execution in the middle of operation because too many temporary objects were created and destroyed.

Comment: its not the `new String()` that slows down ur process its making 50 threads :D. convention for the number of threads is normally `#CORE + 1`

Comment: Did you tried with some lesser no of threads? Pretty sure you wont have 50 cores

Comment: how do you measure this numbers? can you please provide your code? cas there may be a problem in measurement as well.

Comment: I think it could come from the fact that you're passing a byte array, and the bytes have to be converted using the proper encoding. This encoding task is quite long with String methods... ~4 years ago, i found it was a perf bottleneck in a custom MongoDB driver, and actually, MongoDB solved the problem by implementing themselves the conversion from String to UTF8 and vice-versa. Could it be linked with your problem?

Comment: @sjahan yeah bytes to string is heavy on CPU.

Comment: `String("Hello")` means the assignment of an interned string to a new string object. I haven't looked in the Java source code, but I wouldn't be surprised if they will internally even share the same `char[]`.

Comment: @M.leRutte String are immutable, they won't share char[], but its much easier(less intense) to create String("hello") compared to String(bytes)

Comment: @nafas sure? In case of substrings Java does share the `char[]`, so why would it copy an interned string, as it *is* immutable.

Comment: @M.leRutte I'll shave my beard if it does mate :D. even substring creates a new String object.

Comment: @nafas I hope your razor blades are sharp: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#174: // The array representing the String is the same
size as the String, so no point in making a copy.

Comment: @M.leRutte on the original size mate, because technically we really didn't change the object, its like saying `s1 = s2` (no new object was created)!!!

Comment: @nafas you have to make sure to look at the current code though. http://www.grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/lang/String.java?av=f as you can see `new String(String)` produce a new String Object that uses the same backing character array.

Comment: @M.leRutte The substring was changed rather recently so that it actually uses a new character array. http://www.grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/lang/String.java#String.substring%28int%2Cint%29 be careful with grepcode for some reason search results like to refer to java 6.

Comment: @matt @nafas in any case with a `byte[]` it makes a copy, of course. If it wouldn't the resulting `String` wouldn't be immutable as the underlying array isn't immutable.

Comment: You're saying the multi-threaded version is 120 to 210 times slower. While other comments are right that 50 threads with 8 cores will be inefficient because it forces context swapping and there may be some bottleneck provokes internally by memory allocation, that factor sounds large. Can you post a [mcve] ? If overall the program takes the same amount of time but all the threads end up waiting for each other, I'd say it's entirely possible that `String(bytes)` is effectively serialised. `java.nio` may fare better as it is intended to be parallel friendly. May need to look at source to fix.

Comment: This is not reproducible. It goes from taking 100ms to taking 21 seconds. The "optimizations" caused by using new String("hello") versus `new String("hello".getBytes())` do not come into play for a  loop that is being called 2500 times.

Answer (score 2):

### Swap

If the RAM is low, the JVM together with the OS swap to the HDD. Increase the availabe Xmx and Xms for a better Performance.

Comment: @OP I agree with peter, this could be another reason for speed reduction.

Comment: The byte[] would have to be pretty large for this to take effect. If it is on the order of "Hello" then this is a non-factor.

Comment: Since the algorithm was creating and destroying many temporary objects, the memory was indeed part of the problem. I had more than enough memory, but the garbage collector would pause in the middle of operation to clear the memory. Using Xmx was part of the solution. I updated the question to reflect your answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure, it's not `String class`, because they are `immutable`, they have nothing to do with synchronization or threads.

if the number of cores relatively low (say 2) and you make 50 threads, that reduces speeds by quite a large factor. its because you have created extra complexity in your program.

each time your CPU cycles through threads  costs some times,

There is no rule of thumb on choosing number of threads I normally go with :

```
number of Cores + 1
```

**NOTE:**

if you have say lots of API calls I would go for a bigger number of threads, whereas if threads are purely using CPU (as you are using them) then I go for a smaller number of threads (`threads= #cores + 1`)

Comment: My computer has 8 cores. If I run 8 thread, the problem still remains. It becomes 20 times slower when I call new String(byte[]) from 8 threads then when I call it from a single thread.

Comment: how much memory do you have/use? as @peter mentioned it could be the OS Swap. also try with lower  threads and see how it goes!

Comment: It turned out I only have 4 physical cores. My computer lists 8 cores but 4 of them are virtual cores so don't count. Your answer was part of the reason for my problem. I updated the question to reflect that.